# Why is the LibreOffice icon just an X with a circle around it?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, libreoffice

The LibreOffice icon looks OK from within the menu or launchers, but in the window decoration and in the dock it turns into a big X with a circle around it.

I'm using Kubuntu 11.10, by the way, with the 4.8 backports PPA.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

bcooksley is telling on the KDE Forum: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=11834

> That is because the application itself needs to set it's icon. If the
>   application does not set one ( an XImage I believe ) then KDE provides
>   it's default X logo. KDE does not retrieve this icon from the menu,
>   but from X, which does not have a icon set if the application does not
>   set one.
>
> Solution: contact developers of application(s) in question, or edit
>   the source code of them yourself, and compile it.